# Trying to load JSON file into html and then display as table and also making graphs?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, node.js

Hi all I am doing a project where I have connected my raspberry pi to DynamoDB and have managed to scan the database and create the following JSON file:

```
[{
    "Date": "24/02/2020",
    "onTime": "Present",
    "Surname": "Adams",
    "Forename": "Natalie",
    "clockedIn": "18:13:58",
    "StudentID": "0004743621"
}, {
    "Date": "25/02/2020",
    "onTime": "Present",
    "Surname": "Adams",
    "Forename": "Natalie",
    "clockedIn": "12:13:05",
    "StudentID": "0004743621"
}, {
    "Date": "24/02/2020",
    "onTime": "Absent",
    "Surname": "Pilgrim",
    "Forename": "Scott",
    "clockedIn": "NoTime",
    "StudentID": "0004627468"
}, {
    "Date": "25/02/2020",
    "onTime": "Late",
    "Surname": "Pilgrim",
    "Forename": "Scott",
    "clockedIn": "12:44:29",
    "StudentID": "0004627468"
}]
```

I am running a nodeJS server to display a HTML page and have been trying and failing in grabbing the data from the JSON file and then putting it into a table and then also query said table.

Would be a great help if anyone can give me assistance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I like to the d3 library on the client side for this task:
https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-fetch.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

d3.json("/path/to/file.json").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response I have tried entering the code you supplied and keep getting the error:
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: i'd guess your json file isn't being sent as a json file.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have fetched the json in your view, you can:

1. Deserialize the json into objects using `var arr_from_json = JSON.parse( json_string );`.
2. Get the table DOM element: `// Find a <table> element with id="myTable":
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");`
3. For each object in list create a row:
   `var row = table.insertRow(0);`
4. Create as many cells as properties you have in object: `var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);`
5. For each properti of the object add data to the created row cell: `cell1.innerHTML = arr_from_json.myData;`